# How can I book the plane schedule I want from the USA to Japan?

Tags: usa, japan, tickets, airlines

I want to buy a plane ticket from Portland, Oregon (PDX) to Fukuoka, JAPAN (FUK). The most obvious schedule is to take the direct flight from Portland to Tokyo (NRT) on Delta airlines and then a flight from from Tokyo to Fukuoka on either ANA or JAL. The problem is that I cannot get this schedule to appear on any site online site (Delta/Expedia/Travelocity/Orbitz/Kayak/Hipmunk) despite the fact that it seems I that I could buy these tickets separately (ie. the flights are not full). What is going on here? Is there someway I can book this ticket online or is there some reason this schedule can't be ticketed?

*The dates I am trying are PDX->FUK on 26-DEC-2013 - FUK->PDX on 25-JAN-2014*

Comment: are you really planning to come back in the past? :-)

Comment: maybe I don't quite understand your question but if you look on [skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/flights/pdx/fuk/131226/140125/airfares-from-portland-to-fukuoka-in-december-2013-and-january-2014.html) looks like you can book it without problems..

Comment: @Geeo Fixed the dates. Yes, I can see the schedule on skyscanner which forwards me to ebookers to make the reservation. Still don't understand why none of the major online sites wouldn't return this obvious itinerary....

Comment: I think it could be broadened to "Where to book a specific plane schedule".

Comment: I could bring up flights on matrix.itasoftware.com (XLX9ZNJQ fare using either JL or NH for the domestic segments), but could not force Kayak or Orbitz to show them even when trying to force a routing using Multi-City. Interesting.

Comment: Have you called the airline directly? That has worked for me with a similar situation on a completely different route where the one I wanted never appeared.

Comment: @Vince I was originally going to phrase the question that way, but then I though maybe it was too broad.

Comment: @Itai I didn't call the airlines, but I did try Delta, JAL and ANA's web pages....

Comment: @choster Interesting. ita software seems to have a more sophisticated search engine, because it also returns flights with airport changes in Tokyo between the international airport (NRT) and domestic airport (HND) something none of the other sites seem to find.

Comment: @Geeo see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14799/traveling-to-tomorrow-yesterday :)

Comment: matrix.itasoftware has not the goal to sell tickets. They don't forcibly have a more sophisticated search engine, they have a "different" search strategy. And every travel agent may be using a different Search & Pricing strategy, that's why there are so many different prices for each website. So in general, you are not assured to get a specific flight sold at all. For your case, I found the flights with a layover in Tokyo on www.momondo.com

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Portland/Fukuoka) which gives the direct flight as one of the options, and so does [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/flights/pdx/fuk/131226/140125/airfares-from-portland-to-fukuoka-in-december-2013-and-january-2014.html).

The issue you may have been facing is actually for these search engines to describe it may have to do with how far in advance you're looking at, general search display conditions, availability of prices to them, etc