# Westward commercial flights that outpace the Earth's rotation

Tags: air-travel, routes

Are there any commercial flights flying west that outpace the rotation of the Earth? In other words, where the ending longitude is at least (15 degrees * flight duration in hours) west of the starting longitude. While on such a flight, you'd see the Sun going the "wrong" way.

I know such flights are possible at airliner speeds if you're far enough from the equator, but I don't know whether there's actually any cities far enough north with nonstop flights between them.

Comment: The classic case was of course Concorde which did that every day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I land in a different time zone before my take off time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/can-i-land-in-a-different-time-zone-before-my-take-off-time)

Comment: Note that the other question is possibly not an exact duplicate, due to timezone boundaries.

Comment: @jcaron I don't consider that a duplicate, because it basically revolves around going from the west edge of one time zone to the east edge of the next time zone over, which means the Sun won't appear to go in reverse.

Comment: While not exactly what you are looking for, I once took off just before sunset and was headed directly west.  As a result the Sun stayed in the same apparent position for several minutes while the plane was climbing to cruise height.

Comment: Found one, though the difference is tiny. Jetstream is definitely not favourable, a lot of flights are much master the other (much less interesting) way around.

Comment: I guess we should decide if we're going based on block time (scheduled departure to scheduled arrival), or actual flying time from takeoff to landing on a particular day.

Comment: @PeterM You also get some benefit from the increasing altitude - sunset occurs about 1 minute later per km of altitude, so a 6-minute climb to 9km would keep the sun stationary even when heading due north or south!

Comment: For a short flight that came close to this there was a commercial flight from Kangerlussuaq to Iqaluit (about 18 degrees of longitude and 900 km distance) that I think did the distance in a scheduled 1:15 when jets were used in the late 1990's (though service from Greenland before and since used turboprops, which are slower). There is talk of [restarting jet service from Nuuk](https://nunatsiaq.com/stories/article/airlines-look-to-revive-direct-flights-between-iqaluit-and-nuuk-greenland/) when the runway there is made long enough for jets.

Comment: I've seen Superman, this can't end well...

Comment: Flights take shortest distance between destinations along earth's greatest circle. Your question appears to be about flights along parallels.

Comment: @MaxJasper I know flights go along great circles. I don't really care about the details of the route, just that local solar time at landing is earlier than at takeoff.

Comment: Which does imply, thanks to the mean value theorem, that for some portion of the flight, the local solar time was instantaneously going backwards; which is to say that the longitudinal component of the plane's velocity (along the parallel) at that moment was more than 15 degrees per hour.

Comment: Flights are usually along earth's greatest circle. For a westward flight to land such that landing local time is less that takeoff local time, a passenger plane must have a minimum speed of about 1700 km/h. That may be possible soon with newer planes. Now planes speed is around 800 km/h.

Comment: @MaxJasper But the answers show that this is possible now.

Comment: @MaxJasper: That would be the case for a flight along the equator, where 1 degree of longitude = 1/360 of the earth's circumference.  But at a higher latitude, each degree of longitude corresponds to a shorter distance, and 15 degrees per hour may be a reasonable airplane speed.  Near the north pole, the length of a degree of longitude approaches zero, and a snail could achieve the desired feat.

Comment: Flights are always along earth greatest circle, not along parallels.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think Reykjavik to Anchorage should do it. It's 7h:16m flight time and covers 128 degrees longitude (22W to 150W), that comes out to 17.6 degrees per hour.

Iceland Air flies that in summer, but not right now.

Irkutsk to St. Petersburg is close: 100 degrees in 6h:35m. Twice a week on Yakutia.

I used to fly a fair bit Shanghai (PVG) to San Francisco (SFO) on United:  leaves at noon and arrive three hours earlier around 9am. That doesn't count though: it's eastwards crossing the dateline .

Comment: Looks like the block time is 7 hours 20 minutes, so still good there.

Comment: To add time zones: Anchorage runs on [Alaska Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Time_Zone), which is UTC+9 or UTC+8 depending on daylight savings; while [Iceland runs on UTC all year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Iceland).  So that Reykjavik to Anchorage will gain 8 or 9 time zones in its 7h20m, arriving at a local clock time 40mins or 1h40m ahead of when it departed.  On the other hand, St Petersburg is UTC+3, while Irkutsk is UTC+8 — so that flight only gains 5 time zones, not so close to beating its 6h35m.

Comment: @PLL If Iceland Air only flies that trip in the summer, it’ll always be daylight savings time for this trip (AKDT is used Mar–Nov), and so: UTC+8, 8 time zones, land (Anchorage time) 40 minutes before you took off (Reykjavik time).

Answer (score 32):

Inspired by [Russell McMahon's answer to "Can I land in a different time zone before my take off time?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/14503/30703).

The rotational velocity at a given latitude is about:

```
V_rot = 1500 x cos(latitude) km/h
```

Conversely, the latitude at which a given rotational velocity is attained can be found by:

```
latitude = arccos(speed/1500)
```

Most jets have a cruising speed between about 800 km/h (A320 family) to over 900 km/h (777). Not taking into account take-off/ascent/descent/landing, the latitude at which you go "faster than the Earth" at 900 km/h (if you travel parallel to... a parallel) is about 53°, which in the Northern hemisphere is about the middle of England, Northern Germany, or about the middle of the southern provinces of Canada. At 800 km/h, you have to reach nearly 58° (around Stockholm, or close to the limit between the southern and northern provinces of Canada).

There is one additional complication:

- You need to travel along a parallel "or better" (along the great circle route), so any detours due to jet stream, weather or geopolitical issues will make things worse.
- The jet-stream is most likely against you.

So in flight, at cruise altitude, if you manage to avoid the jet-stream, fly with a 270 heading in a 777 over Scandinavia, sure, you will go "faster than Earth" at least temporarily.

I haven't yet found a flight where it actually works from take-off to landing. I suspect it may be quite difficult due to the constraints above. I have tried HEL-OSL and HEL-KEF but neither work.

#### Edit

[According to Flightaware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AFL6290/history/20211214/0330Z/UHMM/UUEE), flight SU6290, GDX-SVO (Magadan to Moscow Sheremetyevo) using a 777, took 7h13 on 14/12/2021, for a [longitude difference of 113°](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=GDX-SVO), which corresponds to a 7h32 time difference. So that flight landed before it took off using local solar time (it also landed before it took off in actual local time), but just barely.

However, during flight, especially the middle part when it was flying a 270 heading over Northern Siberia (somewhere around 70°N) at about 860 km/h, it was very definitely "going faster than the Earth" (over 300 km/h faster!).

Comment: The great circle route may mean you won't spend the entire flight at a heading near 270 - but it may mean that you spend much of it closer to the pole than either the origin or destination.  So it isn't inherently necessary that both cities be very far north/south.  Anyway, since the great circle route is the *shortest* route, then if traveling along a parallel would suffice, the great circle route will do even better.

Comment: Btw, it looks like GDX-SVO was blocked at 8 hours, so it wouldn't qualify based on that.

Comment: "(around Stockholm, or close to the limit between the southern and northern provinces of Canada)" Canada doesn't _have_ "northern provinces".  Those are the territories up there.

Comment: wait what about in the southern hemisphere?  Such as the enormous Australia/Sth America routes, no???

Comment: @NateEldredge Yup, looks like it was a bit too late to write something that makes sense, the great circle route is obviously better than flight along the parallel, don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: @Fattie continents in the Southern Hemisphere do not extend much south. The southernmost city with intercontinental service is probably Melbourne which is only at 37°S. I checked SYD-JNB and SCL-SYD, they're quite far from the mark.

Comment: got it!  thanks for the "I couldn't be bothered glancing at a map"  :) :)

Answer (score 21):

Beginning Summer 2022, Finnair will fly nonstop between Helsinki and Seattle, which are 147°16' apart in longitude, a time equivalent of 9 hours 49 minutes.  The westbound flight has block time of 9 hours 45 minutes, departing Helsinki at 17:55 local time and arriving Seattle at 17:40.  That covers 15°6' of longitude per hour.  Of course, assuming it runs on schedule, the actual flying time would be even shorter.

This is not as impressive as KEF-ANC, but at least it's between larger cities...?

Answer (score 12):

Practically all westward commercial flights from East Asia to central Europe will outpace the Earth's rotation for part of their flight. As these flights are against the jet stream, they tend to choose near-polar routes, flying over very northern latitudes, to decrease travel time. As other answers have already pointed out, a typical cruising speed in ideal conditions is faster than the 15°/h rotation of the Earth North of approximately 50~60 °N. Flying from Japan (Tokyo or Osaka) to Europe (typically Helsinki, although also London and Munich) regularly put me as far North as the Ob estuary in Siberia; using Google Maps that approximates to 70 °N. Even with unfavourable winds, that should give a speed faster than Earth's rotation.

If you take such a flight close to the winter solstice, you can view the sun setting and rising at awkward times and awkward directions while you are flying into and out of the polar night.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 I flew from England to Iceland in late May. Leaving England at sunset, the sun was resting on the horizon. When we landed in Iceland, the sun was noticeably higher. It was the first time I saw the sun "rise in the west."

Comment: This is interesting, but I think it's a different effect than what the question is asking.  This flight wouldn't "outpace the rotation of the earth"; Reykjavik is about 22 degrees west of London, so you'd have to do the flight in about 1.5 hours, but all flights I'm seeing take over 3.  Manchester-Reykjavik is a little closer but still not there.  The solar time when you landed was in fact later than when you departed, but due to Iceland's higher latitude, in spring and summer the sun is higher in the sky than in England at the same solar time.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I hadn't thought of that, but it makes sense.